# How to access & modify Django template context variables

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In my urls.py, I map the url accounts/login/ to the login module, with a reference to the template i want to use:

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'templates/login.html'})
```

This works fine, but I want to change the value of the `next` property, which specified where the user ought to be redirected after a successful login.  How can I access these variables and print their values, and more importantly, how can I modify them?

Thanks!

Comment: What part of the Django documentation have you actually read?  Try reading about http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Context and then updating your question to  be more specific.

Comment: culov, you are trying to do too much in your urls.py.  There's no way you should specify the template there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct the url to a view:

```
(r'^accounts/login/', 'myproj.login.views.mylogin')
```

Then handle redirection in your view code:

```
def mylogin(request, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if 'next_url' in request.session:
            url = request.session['next_url']
            del request.session['next_url']  # Cleaning next_url val
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/%s' % url)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    return login(request, **kwargs)

@csrf_protect
def login(request, template_name='registration/login.html'):
    """Displays the login form and handles the login action."""
    retval = django.contrib.auth.views.login(request, template_name)
    clear_session_data(request.session)
    return retval
```